# Не подхватился atheros AR9485

Tags: wireless

Нетбук acer acpire one - установил убунту, не подхватился atheros AR9485. То есть в lspci видится, а в остальном (ifconfig, iwconfig, rfkill) - нет.

Подскажите, как установить

Comment: Система ⇒ Администрирование ⇒ Дополнительные драйверане пробовали?

Answer (score 1):

Вам не хватает прошивки для чипа платы. У меня была аналогичная ситуация - после того, как подсунул (в соответствии с манкой) файл прошивки чипа - вуфа заработала, причем с более полными возможностями, нежели с вин-дровами (под виндоуз). Гуглите по связке "имя чипа платы + Ваша ОС"